# How can I use the random class in c# to generate a single random number (xna)

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to generate a random number using the `Random` class in c# to draw a texture. I'm trying to draw a texture to a random coordinate on the screen, but when I try to run the code below, the texture keeps moving around random spaces. I need to draw it and have it stay in place.

```
Random _Random = new Random();
private int MaxX;
private int MaxY; //screen height and width 

public Texture2D hat;

//code to load in image

//draw code
spriteBatch.Begin();
int hatx = _Random.Next(1, MaxX);
int haty = _Random.Next(1, MaxY);

spriteBatch.Draw(hat, new Rectangle(hatx, haty, 80, 80), Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: you should initialize hatx,haty only once before the rendering code begins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the calls to `Random.Next` only once for your texture. Currently, you are calling it for every draw operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random _Random = new Random();
private int MaxX;
private int MaxY; //screen height and width 

public Texture2D hat;

//code to load in image

// make sure x and y are initialized only once before rendering loop
int x = _Random.Next(1, MaxX);
int y = _Random.Next(1, MaxY);

//draw code
spriteBatch.Begin();
 int hatx = x;
 int haty = y;

 spriteBatch.Draw(hat, new Rectangle(hatx, haty, 80, 80), Color.White);
 spriteBatch.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that every time draw function calls x and y numbers are changed. Because every time random number generates a new number. So your texture will be moving to different places. What you need to do here is that make two class members X and Y, and on ContentLoad function you generate random numbers and fill X and Y value. And in draw function Use class members X and Y instead of making new X and Y.

Comment: Constant seed for random number generator? *Covers comment with tape, scrolls up, and cries silently on inside*